# pandas scatter_matrix change axis ticks labels is not working

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change the ticks labels of the x and y axis for pandas `scatter_matrix`.
The ticks  are being changed but in another opened empty figure.
here is a working code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = np.random.normal(1, 3, 100)
b = np.random.normal(3, 1, 100)
c = np.random.normal(2, 2, 100)
fig, ax= plt.subplots()
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':a,'B':b,'C':c})
pd.scatter_matrix(df, diagonal='kde')
ax.set_xticklabels(['AA','BB','CC'], fontsize=16)
ax.set_yticklabels(['AA','BB','CC'], fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ax.set_xticklabels`, you can rename the data frame columns before calling the scatter_matrix:

```
pd.scatter_matrix(df.rename(columns={"A": "AA", "B": "BB", "C": "CC"}), diagonal='kde')
```

If you would like to access the axis of a specific [i,j] subplot, you can use:

```
ax = pd.scatter_matrix...
ax[i,j].set_yticklabels...
```